# Having issues with python installing LDAP module. Anyone know what the error here is? Sorry if I'm asking in the wrong place

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

Firstly apologize if this is the wrong spot to ask. I'm trying to make a script to connect LDAP in order to make a script for retrieving user info in Active Directory. I'm having an issue with installing the LDAP module. I was hesitant for asking here and have been trying for quite some time.  Below is the error I keep getting. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

> > > (venv)C:\Users\blong\PycharmProjects\untitled>python -m pip install 
> > >           python-ldap
> > >           Collecting python-ldap
> > >           Using cached 
> > >           https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/93/596f875e003c770447f4b
> > >           99267820a0c769dd2dc3ae3ed19afe460fcbad0/python-ldap-3.2.0.tar.gz
> > >           Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in 
> > >           c:\users\blie\pycharmprojects\unti
> > >           tled\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap) (0.4.5)
> > >           Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1_modules>=0.1.5 in 
> > >           c:\users\blie\pycharmproje
> > >           cts\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-ldap) (0.2.5)
> > >           Installing collected packages: python-ldap
> > >           Running setup.py install for python-ldap ... error
> > >           ERROR: Complete output from command 
> > >           'C:\Users\blie\PycharmProjects\untitled\ve
> > >           nv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, 
> > >           tokenize;**file**='"'"'C:\Users\
> > >           \blie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7g4ghvn\python- 
> > >           ldap\setup.py'"'"';f=ge
> > >           tattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
> > >           (**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'
> > >           "', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 
> > >           '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
> > >           install
> > >           --record 'C:\Users\blie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u_hnxged\install- 
> > >           record.txt
> > >           ' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
> > >           'C:\Users\blie\P
> > >           ycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.7\python-ldap':
> > >           ERROR: running install
> > >           running build
> > >           running build_py
> > >           creating build\lib.win32-3.7
> > >           copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
> > >           copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
> > >           creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\asyncsearch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\pkginfo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           copying Lib\ldap__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap
> > >           creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
> > >           copying Lib\ldap\controls\pagedresults.py -> build\lib.win32- 
> > >           3.7\ldap\controls

```
copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\ldap\controls

copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\sss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\vlv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
copying Lib\ldap\controls\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\controls
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\extop
copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\extop
copying Lib\ldap\extop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\extop
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\schema
copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\schema
copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\schema
copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\schema
copying Lib\ldap\schema\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\ldap\schema
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest
copying Lib\slapdtest\_slapdtest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest
copying Lib\slapdtest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest
running egg_info
writing Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'Doc\.build'
writing manifest file 'Lib\python_ldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\README -> build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.conf -> build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\ca.pem -> build\lib.win32-3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.conf -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs

copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.key -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\client.pem -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gencerts.sh -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs

copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\gennssdb.sh -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.conf -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.key -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
copying Lib\slapdtest\certs\server.pem -> build\lib.win32- 
3.7\slapdtest\certs
running build_ext
building '_ldap' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft 
Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command 
"'C:\Users\blong\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 
'import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\blie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-i
nstall-d7g4ghvn\\python-ldap\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(cod
e, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
'C:\Users\blie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u_hnxged\install-record.txt' 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --inst
all-headers
```

'C:\Users\blie\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\include\site\python3.7\python- 
    ldap'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\blie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
    install-d7g4ghv
    n\python-ldap\

Comment: I think `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft 
Visual C++ Build Tools"` is the crucial message in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install python-ldap
```

pipwin installs precompiled Windows binaries provided by Christoph Gohlke.

Comment: A possible problem with this solution is that `pipwin` installs the SASL version of `python-ldap` which apparently has a dependency on the Cyrus SASL service. Pipwin does not offer you the option to choose the non-SASL version, sadly.